# Reuse listview templates

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project. It has multiple pages with ListViews that display content that requires templates. How can I easily reuse one template thought the whole project because right now I have to update the templates on each page everytime I change something in one.

I have created a template as such in each page's xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:*snip*.Renderers;assembly=*snip*"
         x:Class="*snip*.MainPage">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template1">
            <local:PostViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">
                    . . . 
                </StackLayout>
            </local:PostViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template2">
            <local:PostViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">
                    . . . 
                </StackLayout>
            </local:PostViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:PostTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector" 
                         Template1="{StaticResource template1}"
                         Template2="{StaticResource template2}" ></local:PostTemplateSelector>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:PostListView x:Name="PostListView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateSelector}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Official documentation, always start there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your Datatemplate with Unique key in **App.Xaml** Like,

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
             x:Class="YourAppName.App">  
  <Application.Resources>  
    <ResourceDictionary>  
      <DataTemplate x:Key="lstTemplate">  
          <ViewCell>  
               <------Your Design here------->
          </ViewCell> 
        </DataTemplate>  
    </ResourceDictionary>  
  </Application.Resources>  
</Application>
```

Use that **lstTemplate** key in your Listview Like,

```
<ListView x:Name=lst"  
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Name}"  
                   SeparatorColor="#0094FF" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lstTemplate}">
```

Comment: I have `<local:PostTemplateSelector x:Key="PostTemplateSelector" 
                  TextPostTemplate="{StaticResource TextPostTemplate}">
            </local:PostTemplateSelector>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TextPostTemplate">...` but it keeps saying It can't find TextPostTemplate

Answer (score 2):

You can define the `DataTemplate` as a resource in `App.xaml` and refer to it from individual XAML pages

Comment: How would I refer to it from each XAML page?